# How change value if not manipulate it?

Tags: c, sqlite, sockets, fwrite, fread

Server:

```
void send_list(sqlite3 *db, int sock) {

    int Fwrite,Fread;
    int id_order;
    int bet2=0;
    Booking info;
    char query2[200];


    Fread = FullRead(sock,&bet2,sizeof(bet2));

    if(Fread <0)
    {
        perror("Error to Recive \n");
        exit(1);
    }



    Fwrite = FullWrite(sockREP,&bet2,sizeof(bet2));

    if(Fwrite < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Send \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("bet2: %d\n",bet2 );

    Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.NAME,sizeof(info));

    if(Fread <0)
    {
        perror("Error to Recive \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.SURNAME,sizeof(info));

    if(Fread <0)
    {
        perror("Error to Recive \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.COD_RIC,sizeof(info));

    if(Fread <0)
    {
        perror("Error to Recive \n");
        exit(1);
    }



    struct timeval time;
    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    srand((time.tv_sec*1000)+(time.tv_sec/1000));

    id_order = rand() %100 + 1;


    Fwrite = FullWrite(sockREP,&info.NAME,sizeof(info));

    if(Fwrite < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Send \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fwrite = FullWrite(sockREP,&info.SURNAME,sizeof(info));

    if(Fwrite < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Send \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fwrite = FullWrite(sockREP,&info.COD_RIC,sizeof(info));

    if(Fwrite < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Send \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fwrite = FullWrite(sockREP,&id_order,sizeof(id_order));

    if(Fwrite < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Send \n");
        exit(1);
    }

printf("this bet2: %d\n",bet2 );


    Fwrite = FullWrite(sock,&id_order,sizeof(id_order));

    if(Fwrite < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Send \n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Server2 (SockREP):

```
void recv_list(sqlite3 *db, int sock) {

 int Fwrite,Fread;
 int id_order;
 int bet2=0;
 Booking info;  


    Fread = FullRead(sock,&bet2,sizeof(bet2));

    if(Fread < 0)
    {
       perror("Error to Recive \n");
       exit(1);
    }

    Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.NAME,sizeof(Booking));

    if(Fread < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Receive \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.SURNAME,sizeof(Booking));

    if(Fread < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Receive \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.COD_RIC,sizeof(Booking));

    if(Fread < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Receive \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fread = FullRead(sock,&id_order,sizeof(id_order));

    if(Fread < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Send \n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Client (sock):

```
void getMenu(int sock)
{
    int Fwrite,Fread;
    int id_order;
    int bet2=0;
    Booking info;


    printf("Select Data: ");
    scanf("%d",&bet2);

    Fwrite = FullWrite (sock,&bet2,sizeof(bet2));

    if(Fwrite < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Send \n");
        exit(1);
    }


    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s",&info.NAME);

    printf("Surname: ");
    scanf("%s",&info.SURNAME);

    printf("Medical Code: ");
    scanf("%s",&info.COD_RIC);


    Fwrite = FullWrite(sock,&info.NAME,sizeof(Booking));

    if(Fwrite <0)
    {
        perror("Error to Recive \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fwrite = FullWrite(sock,&info.SURNAME,sizeof(Booking));

    if(Fwrite <0)
    {
        perror("Error to Recive \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    Fwrite = FullWrite(sock,&info.COD_RIC,sizeof(Booking));

    if(Fwrite <0)
    {
        perror("Error to Recive \n");
        exit(1);
    }



    Fread = FullRead(sock,&id_order,sizeof(id_order));

    if(Fread < 0)
    {
        perror("Error to Send \n");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

my problem is:

why in Server the variable bet2 change value after 3 fullread:

1) Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.NAME,sizeof(info));

2) Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.SURNAME,sizeof(info));

3) Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.COD_RIC,sizeof(info));

i try use read(), but the result is equal

the FullRead function is this:

```
ssize_t FullRead(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
{
    size_t nleft = count;
    ssize_t nread;
    while (nleft > 0) 
    {
        if ( (nread = read(fd, buf, nleft)) < 0) 
        {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else 
                exit(nread);
        } 
        else if (nread == 0)
            break;
        nleft -= nread;
        buf += nread;
    }
    buf = 0;
    return (nleft);
}
```

And FullWrite function is this:

```
ssize_t FullWrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    size_t nleft;
    ssize_t nwritten;
    nleft = count;
    while (nleft > 0) {             /* repeat until no left */
        if ( (nwritten = write(fd, buf, nleft)) < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {   /* if interrupted by system call */
                continue;           /* repeat the loop */
            } else {
                return(nwritten);   /* otherwise exit with error */
            }
        }
        nleft -= nwritten;          /* set left to write */
        buf +=nwritten;             /* set pointer */
    }
    return (nleft);
}
```

Comment: You have posted too much code. Please provide a more succinct example of the problem you're facing.

Comment: We don't know how `FullRead` is implemented, you are passing a pointer to `bet2` to it. I suppose `FullRead` is supposed to change the value. I don't understand your question. Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: i try to edit the code to make it more understandable and I added the fullread and fullwrite code implementation

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how the values of various variables (info.NAME, info.SURNAME, bet2. etc) can change, given that nothing in your code is actually setting those values using the `=` operator.

The answer is pointer-aliasing.  For example, `info.SURNAME` is located at a particular location in your computer's memory.  A pointer to that location can be created via the & operator, e.g. `void * ptr = &info.SURNAME`.

Therefore, when you call `FullRead` like this:

```
Fread = FullRead(sock,&info.SURNAME,sizeof(Booking));
```

... you are giving the `FullRead` function the knowledge of where in memory your info.SURNAME char array is, along with the size of that char array, in bytes.

With that information, FullRead() can now write new bytes into the char array.  e.g. it might do something like this:

```
int FullRead(int sock, char * buf, int numBytesInBuf)
{
   // the real code would read bytes from the network but
   // to keep this example simple I'll just declare some dummy data
   char dummyData[] = "blah blah blah";

   int numBytesToCopy = std::min(numBytesInBuf, sizeof(dummyData));
   for (int i=0; i<numBytesToCopy; i++) buf[i] = dummyData[i];
   return numBytesToCopy;
}
```

... and this writes the data into the memory pointed to by `buf`, which is to say, into `info.SURNAME`.

So how would this work with `bet2`, given that `bet2` is not a char array but rather an int?

It works exactly the same way -- `bet2` may be an int, but it still has a location in memory, and a size in bytes (typically either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on what kind of computer you are using), so the same trick works with it... `FullRead()` can write into the memory area where bet2 lives, and thereby change bet2's value by updating its bytes.

```
 Fread = FullRead(sock,&bet2,sizeof(bet2));  // writes new value into bet2!
```